# Apple receipt validation using Scala/Java

Tags: java, scala, security, in-app-purchase

I have a Scala backend where I want to validate in-app purchase receipts, without having to rely on the remote App Store service, which introduces extra delays and an additional point of failure.

Therefore, I want to locally validate the PKCS#7 signature included in the receipt.

Apple has some documentation on the subject on the link below, but it uses the iOS Objective-C API, and I've had some trouble trying to map that to the Java security API.

From the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html), code listing 1-4:

```
BIO *b_p7; /* The PKCS #7 container (the receipt) */
PKCS7 *p7; /* and the output of the verification. */

BIO *b_x509; /* The Apple root certificate, as raw */
X509 *Apple; /* data and in its OpenSSL representation. */

/* The root certificate for chain-of-trust verification. */
X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();

/* Initialize b_out as an output BIO to hold the receipt payload */
BIO *b_out = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

/* Capture the content of the receipt file. */
p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(b_p7, NULL);

Apple = d2i_X509_bio(b_x509, NULL); /* Initialize b_x509 as an input BIO with a value of the Apple */
X509_STORE_add_cert(store, Apple); /* root certificate and load it into X509 data structure. */

/* Verify the signature. If the verification is correct, */
/* b_out will contain the PKCS #7 payload and rc will be 1. */
int rc = PKCS7_verify(p7, NULL, store, NULL, b_out, 0);
```

I found a few solutions online, using different APIs (Oracle security, Sun security, Bouncy Castle) and different methods within the same API, but none of them seems to work. And none of them seems to be simple enough for someone without much security knowledge to figure out why.

One thing that confuses me is that some methods use the signature and the unsigned content to check if they match, but others (including Apple's code sample) validate the signature on its own, just using the certificate that signed it. Which approach is correct?

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction (right library, tutorial, code sample, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: mr. Downvoter, care to explain?